# Transfer Clash of Clans account from one G+ to another G+ account?

Tags: clash-of-clans, android

I want to give my account to someone but I want to keep my G+ account. I hold this G+ account very dear to me and I can't give it up.

I've watched some clips about transferring accounts to another device. But I haven't found a video on how to transfer Clash of Clans account from one G+ to another G+ account.

I am using android OS.

EDIT:

I managed to transfer account but if someone else has your Gmail and pass then they can take it.

Comment: can you dedicate one of his devices for your google account?

Comment: I haven't tried that. What I did is attached another G+ to my device and tried to connect to Clash. I will try that too. I am opened to more ideas.

Comment: you could use the link a device option

Comment: As drop dead mentioned, you can link a device. Options can be found in settings. Note that this will not transfer but copy your village to his/her device. And you both can continue to use the same village at a time.

Answer (score 7):

You cannot directly transfer your Clash of Clans account to a different G+ account without contacting [Clash of Clan's support](http://supercell.helpshift.com/a/clash-of-clans/?p=web&f=how-to-contact-us&s=hot-topics) (not sure if they would even let you do this).

Note: [It is illegal per their Terms of Service to buy, sell, or trade villages.](http://supercell.helpshift.com/a/clash-of-clans/?p=web&s=my-account&f=can-i-buy-sell-or-share-accounts)

If you want that person to have access to your village, I would recommend dedicating a device of theirs to just your account.

Comment: you could use the link a device option